# Is it possible to pick a vehicle as your commander?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I'm making a commander deck, I've never played or deckbuilded in this game mode.
I've run across the [Parhelion II](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bParhelion%20II%5d) card and I was wondering if it could be my commander. I know it's not a creature, but since planeswalkers can be commanders, I don't know if the vehicles can or can't be used as commander.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, it can't be used as a commander. And for the record, most planeswalkers can't be used either; only [those who explicitly state that they can](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5B%22can%20be%20your%20commander%22%5D). It's stated that way in the [Comprehensive Rules](https://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/rules):

> 903.3. Each deck has a legendary creature card designated as its commander. This designation is not a characteristic of the object represented by the card; rather, it is an attribute of the card itself. The card retains this designation even when it changes zones.
> Example: A commander that’s been turned face down (due to Ixidron’s effect, for example) is still a commander. A commander that’s copying another card (due to Cytoshape’s effect, for example) is still a commander. A permanent that’s copying a commander (such as a Body Double, for example, copying a commander in a player’s graveyard) is not a commander.

> 903.3a Some cards have an ability that states the card can be your commander. This ability modifies the rules for deck construction, and it functions before the game begins. See also rule 113.6n.

Of course, Commander is a casual format, so if your playgroup likes your idea of a Parhelion II Commander deck, they might allow it as a house rule.

Comment: +1 for casual format mention. Make the deck. Use it. **BUT**: always have the conversation before the game starts, especially with people you've never played with before: "Hey, y'all: I have this deck that I've made that uses Parhelion II as the commander. Is everyone cool with me using it? If not, that's totally fine, I have <insert other mono-white commander here> that can also be the commander," then shuffle up and play.

Answer (score 2):

While you cannot pick that specific vehicle as your commander, you can pick [Shorikai, Genesis Engine](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shorikai%2C%20Genesis%20Engine), released in Neon Dynasty Commander after this question was posted. It is a Vehicle that can be your commander via an explicit rules text clause. Plus, its colour identity is blue-white, so you can include Parhelion II in a deck with it.